# Kotlin VideoView path with a changing resource name

Tags: kotlin, android-videoview

I have a group of mp4 files (v1.mp4, v2mp4,...) inside the raw folder.
**I need to read them randomly after a button is clicked.**

I get the message "not possible to play this video".

If I point to a specific file in the setVideoPath, ("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.v2) the video is played, but do not change when the button is hit.

My code is the following:

```
fun onClick(view: View) {
        // Change the word randomly
        randOne = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, wordMap.size)
        val display : TextView = findViewById(txtWord)
        val randKey = randOne.toString()
        display.text = wordMap[randKey]
        val vdFile = "v$randKey"

        // Create conditions to run the video files
        val video : VideoView = findViewById(vdWord)
        video.setVideoPath("android.resource://$packageName/R.raw.$vdFile")
        video.start()
        video.setOnCompletionListener { video.start() }

    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var videoName = "youChoose"
val video: Uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/raw/$videoName")
simpleVideoView!!.setVideoURI(video)
```